# Period in composition of functions

Tags: periodic-functions, function-and-relation-composition

Consider $f \circ \ g \circ \ h \circ \dots \circ z(x)$ is composition of functions . Now when we can say this composition is periodic ? Also how we can compute period of that ?
I think only last function had to be periodic .

Comment: It suffices for the last function to be periodic; the other functions don't matter much one way or the other unless they are really specifically tailored to force the result to be periodic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Okay and what about period ?

Comment: Again, unless the other functions are really specific (for example if they are constant), the period will typically be the period of the last function. This isn't always true, e.g. we might have $z(x) = \sin x$ and $y(z) = z^2$, in which case $y(z(x)) = \sin^2 x$ has half the period.

Comment: So there is no general way for calculating period. Is that right ?

Comment: It depends on what you know about the other functions.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Suppose we know relation of the other functions completely.